# Getting new pathname after history.goBack() in a react App

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

In a `React` App, I want to implement `Back Button`. if I'm in `http://localhost:8000/login/` and then if I do this:

```
history.goBack();
```

It works and the address bar in the browser changes. for example  it changes to  `http://localhost:8000/dashboard/`. then I need the ned path and do this:

```
console.log(window.location);
```

the output is this:
[image]

And I expect if I code `console.log(window.location.pathname)` or `console.log(history.location.pathname)` I will get `/dashboard/`. but I get `/login/` that is my previous location.

My question is that I see new location(`/dashboard/`) in the console but `console.log(window.location.pathname)` gives me another thing! how this is possible?

I need new path to render new component based on that but every time I'm one step behind.

Comment: are you using any router?

Comment: Yes, Im using useHistory and BrowserRouter as Router

Comment: you may not need `useHistory`; components rendered with `<Route />` have a `history` prop on them

Comment: See this demo: https://z8myr.csb.app/ Navigate to Dashboard, then Login, and then click Back and check out the console